# Comparing two dates with an insert trigger

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I want to make sure that the suborder date is not before the orderdate using this trigger:::

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER suborder_date before
  INSERT ON suborder FOR EACH row DECLARE suborder_dd DATE;
  orderdate DATE;
  BEGIN
    SELECT reqshipdate INTO suborder_dd FROM suborder;
    SELECT orders.orddate INTO orderdate FROM orders;
    IF orderdate < suborder_dd THEN
      raise_application_error(-20002,('Required Ship Date is before Order Date'));
    END IF;
  END;
```

This compiles now I want to test it and insert this into the table...
insert into suborder values (1,1,'12-Jan-13','13-Jan-14', 'Office Depot', 1)

> Error: Error starting at line 1 in command: insert into suborder
>   values (1,1,'12-Jan-13','13-Jan-14', 'Office Depot', 1) Error report:
>   SQL Error: ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number
>   of rows ORA-06512: at "BB.SUBORDER_DATE", line 4 ORA-04088: error
>   during execution of trigger 'BB.SUBORDER_DATE'
>   01422. 00000 -  "exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows"
>   *Cause:    The number specified in exact fetch is less than the rows returned.
>   *Action:   Rewrite the query or change number of rows requested

With the help of others I finally got the output that I wanted when I edited the command for myself. Thank you!

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER suborder_date BEFORE
  INSERT ON suborder FOR EACH row DECLARE reqship DATE; orderdate date;
  BEGIN
    SELECT o.orddate
    INTO orderdate
    FROM orders o
    WHERE o.orderno = :new.orderno;
    IF orderdate     > :new.reqshipdate THEN
      raise_application_error(-20002, ('Required Ship Date is before Order Date'));
    END IF;
  END;
```

Comment: Please only use tags that are appropriate to your question.

Comment: `SELECT reqshipdate INTO suborder_dd FROM suborder;` will try to read **all** rows from the suborder table into a single variable - do you really think that is going to work? Same with the second statement. And you don't need to `select` values in a row level trigger, everything is available in the `new` variable.

Comment: So the proper way is to declare variables? make one for reqshipdate? Should I use a cursor?

Comment: Expanding on horsey's comment, remove the first SELECT and use "IF orderdate < :new.reqshipdate THEN"

Comment: If I already have a table with orders and suborders and I want to check that a certain order's suborder is shipped after the date that the order is placed, then won't I need to have a join clause to indicate that order.orderno = suborder.orderno inside the trigger? Else how would I be able to compare if the suborder required ship date is after the respective order date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you follow the comments, you should get something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER suborder_date
  BEFORE INSERT ON suborder 
  FOR EACH row 
  DECLARE 
    orderdate DATE;
  BEGIN

    SELECT o.orddate
    INTO   orderdate
    FROM   orders o
    WHERE  o.order_id = :new.order_id;

    IF orderdate < :new.suborder_dd THEN
      raise_application_error(-20002, ('Required Ship Date is before Order Date'));
    END IF;
  END;
```

Comment: Thank you! I finally got the output that I wanted when I edited the command for myself.